# Double Tap detect distance increase in HammerJS

Tags: distance, tap, hammer.js

Im using Hammer JS to detect mobile gestures.

Im having little issue with double tap.

Currently in hammer js double tap is detected if a person taps 2 times where the 1st tap point and 2nd tap point should be the same or near to each other.

Example 1 :

**1st tap point** = position 0px, **2nd tap point** = position 3px

Hammer JS can detect the doubletap event since the 2 points are near to each other. Ive also tested this in my android phone using chrome browser.

Example 2 :

**1st tap point** = position 0px, **2nd tap point** = position 10x

Hammer JS CANNOT detect the double tap event since the 2 points are far to each other.

How do i do it in Hammer JS so it could detect double tap even if the 2 tap points are far to each other.

I want something like this :

```
mc.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 2, maxDistance : 10 }));
```

Does anyone know if this is possible in HammerJS?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Increasing posThreshold in the recognizer options should do the trick.

```
mc.add(new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'doubletap', taps: 2, threshold: 10, posThreshold: 10 }));
```

See Hammer's tap docs here: http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-tap/